# How to clear a cell if a selected dropdown option is not equal to a value or if its cleared with backspace?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like that the date on column F to be cleared if the dropdown on column E is set to an option different that "NO VOLVER A LLAMAR" (see image below), or if the cell is cleared with backspace.

Since I'm a noob with Apps Script, I haven't tried anything yet...

[image: my google sheet]

Answer (score 0):

Clear F if E is not equal "NO VOLVER A LLAMAR"

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() != "Your sheet name" || e.range.columnStart != 4 || e.value != "NO VOLVER A LLAMAR")return;
  e.range.offset(0,1).setValue("");
}
```

You cannot run these functions without supplying the event object. If you attempt to run from the script editor without supplying the event object you will get an error.  The onEdit trigger is a simple trigger meaning that it cannot perform functions that require permission.  If you need to perform commands that require permission you must create an installable trigger either programmatically or through the editors trigger panel.

There are several limitations running scripts this way.  You will have difficulty using alert and prompt boxes.  They are fairly difficult to debug because the onEdit is not easily run in debug mode so you are left having to edit the appropriate elements on the desired sheet."